# Can I use Mic to input Frequency Meter circuit?

Tags: frequency, meter

Í'm new to application level of electronics that I'm studying.I have a project to do in college and I was thinking to do a Frequency Meter circuit that can measure the frequency of given input signal and display it on an LCD display.

I using this circuit as reference:

[image: circuit]

I wondering if I can use input from a mic to measure the frequency of sound ( human voice or anything )

Hep appreciated very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just connecting a microphone to the input of this circuit won't yield what you want.

First, microphone signals are very small, and this single-transistor amplifier has unpredictable gain, but not enough for a typical microphone to make a 5 V digital signal in any case.

Second, human voice contains a lot of harmonics.  The dominant frequency is often not even the fundamental.  This means there will be more zero crossings than what just a pure tone of the "same" frequency would produce.  You will not only have to amplify the microphone signal more, and more predictably, but you will also have to do some filtering to try to pick out the dominant frequency from the voice.

Comment: is it hard to do that? I was thinking of doing this for college project.

Comment: @Suchit: Obviously I can't answer how hard it is for *you* to do this.  Creating the right amp for a microphone and adding some filtering would be a good learning experience for anyone persuing electrical engineering though.

Answer (score 0):

The given circuit does not have the input sensitivity to use with a microphone directly. You'll need a preamplifier to bring the microphone's signal up to line level (1 V<sub>p-p</sub> or more).

Comment: I think the circuit also uses a form of aliasing/down-conversion to measure 60MHz too.

Comment: do you think I can measure frequency of sounds in real world environment rather than just oscillator generated signals?

Comment: @Andyaka: No, there's no aliasing or down-converting, just a hardware counter (prescaler) inside the PIC that's capable of counting at 60 MHz.

Comment: @Suchit: Real-world sounds rarely consist of a single tone or "frequency", as Olin has pointed out. This type of frequency counter will give erratic results when presented with two or more frequencies simultaneously.

Comment: @DaveTweed Okay, but i guess it can be used to tune musical intruments, measure radio frequency etc, right?Do you know of any other applications?

Comment: You'd be surprised. Musical instruments do not produce pure tones, either (flute comes closest). Also, to tune a musical instrument, you need to be able to read frequency with a resolution on the order of 0.06% (i.e., 600 ppm, 1/100 of a semitone), which corresponds to a resolution of 0.15 Hz at middle C (261.63 Hz). This is not a trivial thing to do.

Comment: What you really should do first is connect your microphone to an oscilloscope and see if *you* can figure out the frequency based on what you see there. Then you'll have an appreciation for what a circuit to automate the process has to deal with.